# How to enable local file links in Firefox (on Windows)

Tags: firefox, browser

I found threads like this to enable links to local files: [How do I instruct Firefox to allow me to open file:/// URLs on a localhost-server http:// webpage?](https://superuser.com/questions/1513156/how-do-i-instruct-firefox-to-allow-me-to-open-file-urls-on-a-localhost-serve)

but unfortunately, the solution posted at that link does not work for me.  I have a local web page I made hosted on a local web server and that has links in it to local files and folders (which work when I right click, copy the url, and pasted the url in the address bar of a new tab, but do not work otherwise).  Here is the entire content of the policies.json file I put in "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\distribution":

```
    {
      "policies": {
         "LocalFileLinks": ["http://127.0.0.1:8000",
                       "http://127.0.0.1"]
        }
      }
    }
```

When I click on a link to the local file it writes an error to the developer console that says:

> Security Error: Content at http://127.0.0.1:8000 may not load or link
> to file:///S:/myfile.mp4.

I am trying to get this to work on Firefox 84.0.2 (64 bit).

Any help or hints about how to allow this would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For whom it's still worth today, I happened to encounter the same issue recently and somehow managed to solve it based on [this guide](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work). Basically, you just locate your Mozilla profile folder, create a user.js file and add a few lines to it:

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "http://127.0.0.1:8000");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

The change should be applied after restart your browser.

Comment: Considering the age of the linked article and contributions for it, I was absolutely surprised that it turned out actually working. Thanks!